# Time series classification and auto correlation

Tags: time-series, classification, data-mining

I am trying to understand time series data and data mining. I am trying to classify EEG data set. The classes are known in advance for the data set and the algorithm is trained on the example data set. I understand that the goal is first to understand the distinctive features distinguishing classes from each other and then classify every new row that gets into the system. Does auto correlation make it hard to understand the nature or characteristics of the data?

Comment: What are the features in your case? Am I correct assuming, that you have lots of time series which are classified according to some distance measure?

Comment: I don't quite get your question... Autocorrelation is just a characteristic of the data. Once you have detected it, it is neither hard nor easy to understand, it is just a characteristic. Perhaps you wonder if it is hard to understand how it came about, what was its cause? Then it depends on the context, but quite often you can easily guess what could be driving the autocorrelation, e.g. seasonality or bid-ask bounce (for financial time series).

Comment: The features are the position of the electrodes placed on the scalp.The velocity at which the data gets captured is high.I have been reading that data mining techniques may not work well with time series data because of the nature and characteristics of the time series.Therefore some king of preprocessing methods should be applied before running the data mining algorithms.In this context,autocorrelation may help in predictive analysis, but don't you think for classification and clustering techniques where the algorithm should understand & learn the data well,it might make the learning harder?